# Unable to open the file using fileopener IONIC 4 Cordova

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native, fileopener2

I am trying to download the pdf from the server link to the local storage and then open the local pdf using the fileopener2. **I am currently concerned with the android only.**

But due to some reason, it is giving me the  following error
[image]

Following the code of my various files

**documents.page.ts**

```
viewPDF(downloadURL) {
console.log("jello");
this.miscService.nowLoader();
let path = this.file.dataDirectory;

const transfer = this.filetransfer.create();

transfer.download(downloadURL, `${path}myfile.pdf`).then(entry => {
  let url = entry.toURL();
  console.log(this.platform.platforms);

  if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    console.log("IN IOS");
    this.documentviewer.viewDocument(url, 'application/pdf', {});
    this.miscService.hideLoader();
  } else {
    console.log("IN Android");
    console.log(url);
    
    this.fileopener.open(url, 'application/pdf').then(()=>{
      console.log("File opened");
    },
    err => {
      console.log("Error "+err.message);
    }

    );
    this.miscService.hideLoader();
  }
});
}
```

**I have tried reading all the stackoverflow articles and unable to get it done. Can anyone see something wrong with this code?**